# List of ALL MimeTypes on the Planet, mapped to File Extensions?

Tags: mime-types, file-extension

Is there a resource that lists ALL the mimeTypes in existence?

I have found a few places with under 1000 mimeTypes, but then they still don't include common ones like .rar, .fla, .rb, .docx!

Does anyone have a COMPLETE list of mimetypes?  Not down to the most obsure "company-only" ones, but at least all of the ones we might use.

Also, I'm looking for a list that maps file extensions to mimeTypes.

Comment: I made this array pastebin.com/d4ZQBe5A or http://gist.github.com/nimasdj/801b0b1a50112ea6a997 by joining all the following lists + .php extension which is missing in all of them. 
please contribute to this list to make it as accurate and complete as possible. 
https://gist.github.com/plasticbrain/3887245
http://pastie.org/5668002
http://pastebin.com/iuTy6K6d

total: 1223 extensions as of 16 November 2015

Answer (score 64, accepted):

http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/ lists the "official" mime-types, but it doesn't prevent anyone making their own an not registering it with IANA.

Comment: is there anything that maps them to file extensions? it doesn't look like iana does...

Comment: Whilst you can find lists of file extensions mapped to mime-types (ie. http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/mime-types-full), most lists are not comprehensive. Additionally, a file extension may map to multiple mime-types as it may be used by more than one application. http://filext.com/ is a site you might find useful.

Comment: There is a pretty good list on http://stdicon.com : http://www.stdicon.com/mimetypes

Comment: I agree, Paul Tarjan list is actually very complete!

Comment: The iana.org list misses some very common ones like `.jpg`. It has `.jpeg`, but IMHO leaving stuff like that make the content difficult to use without manipulation.

Comment: @PaulTarjan: your links have disappeared ...

Comment: the stdicon list is archved by the wayback machine at http://web.archive.org/web/20110619062307/http://www.stdicon.com/mimetypes

Comment: The IANA list is missing a few obvious ones, like GPX files. Another useful list is Apache's list, which is in the public domain: https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/branches/1.3.x/conf/mime.types

Comment: https://api.jsonbin.io/b/61b6871862ed886f915f0274 a JSON version of this list

Answer (score 34):

Here's the most up-to-date mime.types maintained by the Apache HTTPD community:
http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/httpd/httpd/branches/2.2.x/docs/conf/mime.types?view=annotate

Comment: Latest version: http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/httpd/httpd/trunk/docs/conf/mime.types?view=markup

Comment: [PHP mapping with extension as key and mime as value, assessed from the latest SVN version pointed out by Teddy](https://gist.github.com/nicStuff/0d92eb03461d24306db8)

Comment: Unfortunately, does not even list `gz` as file extension for `application/gzip`...

Answer (score 8):

[IANA lists the official ones.](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/)  A list which includes file extensions which I find useful is the one included as `/etc/mime.types` in Debian & Ubuntu.

[The Apache web server project also maintains a list.](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/httpd/httpd/trunk/docs/conf/mime.types?view=markup)

Comment: mime.types is also available on some other systems (/etc/apache2/mime.types in OS X)

Answer (score 7):

I collected MIME types and file extensions from many sites and lists, and here's the result: https://s-randomfiles.s3.amazonaws.com/mime/allMimeTypes.txt

I also created a JSON file: https://s-randomfiles.s3.amazonaws.com/mime/allMimeTypes.json

Please tell me if something is missing or incorrect

Comment: it's just missing some standards ;) see https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xml#examples for official ones, yours is a good extra. thanks

Comment: Your second link is broken, it seems. Can you remove the shorteners?

Comment: @Laurel It works fine for me, but I can do it later. Also, I know I should update the list.. (Yeah..)

Comment: @SWdV Can you at least use the full URL? Short links are blacklisted now.

Comment: @Laurel I don't have any problems with the links (how is it possible you do?) Anyway, here are the links: [txt](https://s-randomfiles.s3.amazonaws.com/mime/allMimeTypes.txt), [json](https://s-randomfiles.s3.amazonaws.com/mime/allMimeTypes.json). I didn't have much time earlier.

Comment: @SWdV We probably live in different regions. ISPs can and do sniff network traffic and refuse to send packets from certain sites (net neutrality is dead `:(`). I encountered this during my one internship, and the symptoms look the same.

Comment: I came across an `<img src="data:image/x-jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQ...">` image yesterday.  Not sure how it got its MIME type, but it was a Microsoft Authenticator QR codes pasted somehow into a TinyMCE edit field.  One more for the list anyway I guess.

Answer (score 5):

[iana](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/index.html) is tracking the official ones but of course folks can always declare their own...

In other words, it is doubtful you'll ever get the **full list on the Planet**.

Also consider the case of NPAPI plugins which declare MIME-types just to be be easily accessible... and these MIME-types might be not interesting to you for a reason or another.

Answer (score 3):

If your are using Java you could use Apache Tika, which is a powerful library for dealing with file types. With it you can easily get the preferred extension related to a mime type with a couple of rows:

```
TikaConfig config = TikaConfig.getDefaultConfig();
MimeType mimeType = config.getMimeRepository().forName("image/png"); //Generally your textual mime type
String extension = mimeType.getExtension();
// this would return the extension with the dot. For "image/png" returns ".png"
```

In this way you don't have to mess with downloading and parsing a file with the associations, I find it very comfortable. This is the way I've done the trick.

Answer (score 2):

There is a good Mime Type Table you can find on https://drive.google.com/open?id=0By00BwrZ8886VUg3ak9faG5mTU0
Which is updated 27-02-2017.
I am sure that meet your all needful mime type.

Comment: Link works for me. @Sz: you're right, the list is complete.

Answer (score 1):

There's a good table in the classic book "HTTP: The Definitive Guide" by Gourley and Totty (O'Reilly, with a squirrel on the cover) in Appendix D.  It appears to be complete and up-to-date as of the time the book was written (in 2002).  That was a long time ago, but you'll find all the old favorites there as well as obscure "company-only" ones.

ISBN 1-56592-509-2, http://oreilly.com/catalog/9781565925090/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full list that is easy on the eyes:

http://www.webmaster-toolkit.com/mime-types.shtml

Comment: This list is wrong, it lists mp3 as video as well as audio

Answer (score 0):

User Paul Tarjan said in a comment:

> There is a pretty good list on stdicon.com : [stdicon.com/mimetypes](http://www.stdicon.com/mimetypes)

This website is no longer available, but the most recent archive is https://web.archive.org/web/20161015175648/http://www.stdicon.com/mimetypes

Note that this site doesn't mention "application/x-zip-compressed" (and it's not because of the escaping of slashes either) so it's not perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I took the list from [Apache mime.types](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/httpd/httpd/trunk/docs/conf/mime.types?view=markup) as of Fri Sep 29 15:10:29 2017 UTC and wrote a script to convert it to a **json mapping**. The json is too big for stackoverflow answer. You can find it [here mimes.json](https://paste.ee/p/bQmQH).

script to generate the mapping:

```
# mime_to_json.py
# get the mime.types from
# http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/httpd/httpd/trunk/docs/conf/mime.types?view=markup

import sys
import re
import json

mapping = {}
with open(sys.argv[1], "r") as handle:
    for line in handle:
        line = line.strip()
        if line[0] == "#":
            continue
        parts = re.split("\s+", line)
        mime = parts[0]
        del parts[0]
        for ext in parts:
            mapping[ext] = mime

print(json.dumps(mapping, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```