# Any way to guess the mime type on Delphi XE2?

Tags: delphi, mime-types, content-type, delphi-xe2

I need to guess the mime type with the purpose of fill the "Content-Type" header for some file uploads.

I fail to found a solution for it.

I wish to call something like: `GetMimeType('C:File.jpg')` and get back `image/jpg`.

Best if is multiplataform (for win/osx) but will be enough if only for windows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Internet Direct (Indy) contains a class for this:

class TIdThreadSafeMimeTable

in unit IdCustomHTTPServer

Code example in a HTTP server application:

```
Response.ContentType :=
  Response.HTTPServer.MIMETable.GetFileMIMEType(FileName);
```

Answer (score 9):

Try using the [FindMimeFromData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms775107%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Function.

> FindMimeFromData contains hard-coded tests for (currently 26) separate
>   MIME types (see [Known MIME Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775147.aspx#Known_MimeTypes)). This means that if a given buffer
>   contains data in the format of one of these MIME types, a test exists
>   in FindMimeFromData that is designed (by scanning through the buffer
>   contents) to recognize the corresponding MIME type.

from urlmon.pas

```
function FindMimeFromData(
    pBC: IBindCtx;                      // bind context - can be nil
    pwzUrl: LPCWSTR;                    // url - can be nil
    pBuffer: Pointer;                   // buffer with data to sniff - can be nil (pwzUrl must be valid)
    cbSize: DWORD;                      // size of buffer
    pwzMimeProposed: LPCWSTR;           // proposed mime if - can be nil
    dwMimeFlags: DWORD;                 // will be defined
    out ppwzMimeOut: LPWSTR;            // the suggested mime
    dwReserved: DWORD                   // must be 0
  ): HResult; stdcall;
```

Also this article to see hot it works [`MIME Type Detection in Internet Explorer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms775147%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 7):

IE uses [`GetClassFileOrMime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775108%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`FindMimeFromData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775107%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API to detect the mime type of data/files (`UrlMon` unit in Delphi).

[MIME Type Detection in Internet Explorer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775147.aspx)

The CLSID returned from `GetClassFileOrMime` could be located in the registry under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\<clsid>\MimeTypes`. (also `FileExtensions`, `FriendlyName`).

The registry also holds a MIME database under: `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MIME\Database\Content Type`.

But since the list of [known MIME types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775147.aspx#Known_MimeTypes) is relatively small you could hold that as a resource XML (or whatever) and simply fetch it from there. This will supprt both Windows and OSX.

---

For file upload operation you can simply always use `application/octet-stream`.
Indy has `TIdMimeTable` class (`IdGlobal`) and it uses a fixed list plus inspecting the registry `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` (see `FillMimeTable`). If no match is found `application/octet-stream` is used.
You should probably want to inspect the file *content* at the server side once the file is uploaded, and not rely on the headers because the `ContentType` could be  tampered at the client side, and also not match with the registry at the server-side.

Answer (score 5):

How many file types are you talking about? Maybe you can just create a list of types you want to support.

I can imagine these lists to be available on the internet as well, for instance

- here: http://www.webmaster-toolkit.com/mime-types.shtml
- here: http://webdesign.about.com/od/multimedia/a/mime-types-by-file-extension.htm
- here: [List of ALL MimeTypes on the Planet, mapped to File Extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735659/list-of-all-mimetypes-on-the-planet-mapped-to-file-extensions)
- here: http://hul.harvard.edu/ois/systems/wax/wax-public-help/mimetypes.htm

Just get the file extension using `ExtractFileExt` and check it agains one of those lists. A file doesn't have a mime type in it, so you'll need to use either this list of file extensions, or determine the type by reading the file headers, which is harder and just as unreliable.