# Detecting the Mime-Type of a file on a remote server with INDY

Tags: delphi, mime-types, indy

I have been using the Synapse library to download files from the internet, but I have recently converted my application to use INDY instead and I am missing one of the nicer features in the Synapse library which is the ability to easily get the Mime-Type of a file that I was downloading from a server before saving it to my local machine. Does INDY have this feature and if so how do I go about accessing it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can issue an HTTP `HEAD` request and check the `Content-Type` header. Before you actually `GET` the file (download) :

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Url: string;
  Http: TIdHTTP;
begin
  Url := 'http://yoursite.com/yourfile.png';
  Http := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  try
    Http.Head(Url);
    ShowMessage(Http.Response.ContentType); // "image/png"
  finally
    Http.Free;
  end;
end;
```

The `ContentType` you receive back depends on the web server implementation and is not guaranteed to be the same on each and every server.

---

The other option, is to actually `GET` the file and save it's content to a memory stream such as `TMemoryStream` (not to a local file). Indy provides an overload:

```
Http.Get(Url, AStream);
```

Then you check the `Http.Response.ContentType`, and Save the stream to file: `AStream.SaveToFile`.

---

Not sure about the relevancy here, but note also that Indy can return/guess the mime type of a local file as well (given a file extension). with `GetMIMETypeFromFile` (uses `IdGlobalProtocols`). See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9856265/any-way-to-guess-the-mime-type-on-delphi-xe2).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It seems like a backwards way of doing things compared to the way that Synapse works, but it works in the end that is all that matters.

Comment: "It seems like a backwards way...": I never used Synapse. you could edit your question and post the code you used with Synapse and I might try to guess how it's done there (I also believe source code is available). What I do know, is that any HTTP client (Idny/Synapse/other) either needs to request HEAD - which will not download the server content, or GET - which will download the content first (or stream it to memory). See my edit.

Comment: Yeah with Synapse you just check for the mimtype of the file as it's getting downloaded and before it's actually saved. I guess your stream code is closer to the way that Synapse does it, but either way it works so I am not complaining, just not what I was used to.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can build your function

```
function GetMIMEType(sFile: TFileName): string;
var aMIMEMap: TIdMIMETable;
begin
  aMIMEMap:= TIdMIMETable.Create(true);
    try
  result:= aMIMEMap.GetFileMIMEType(sFile);
    finally
      aMIMEMap.Free;
    end;
  end;
```

And then call

```
procedure HTTPServerGet(aThr: TIdPeerThread; reqInf: TIdHTTPRequestInfo;
                                             respInf: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
var localDoc: string;
    ByteSent: Cardinal;
begin
  //RespInfo.ContentType:= 'text/HTML';
  Writeln(Format('Command %s %s at %-10s received from %s:%d',[ReqInf.Command, ReqInf.Document, 
                       DateTimeToStr(Now),aThr.Connection.socket.binding.PeerIP,
                       aThr.Connection.socket.binding.PeerPort]));
  localDoc:= ExpandFilename(Exepath+'/web'+ReqInf.Document);
  RespInf.ContentType:= GetMIMEType(LocalDoc);
  if FileExists(localDoc) then begin
    ByteSent:= HTTPServer.ServeFile(AThr, RespInf, LocalDoc);
    Writeln(Format('Serving file %s (%d bytes/ %d bytes sent) to %s:%d at %s',
          [LocalDoc,ByteSent,FileSizeByName(LocalDoc), aThr.Connection.Socket.Binding.PeerIP,
           aThr.Connection.Socket.Binding.PeerPort, dateTimeToStr(now)]));
  end else begin
    RespInf.ResponseNo:= 404; //Not found RFC
    RespInf.ContentText:=
          '<html><head><title>Sorry WebBox Error</title></head><body><h1>' +
    RespInf.ResponseText + '</h1></body></html>';
  end; 
end;
```

Comment: I already mentioned Indy's `GetMIMETypeFromFile` (Which I kinda regret I did). Your code is the **server** side implementation of reporting back the content type. OP asks about HTTP **client**. but on the other hand this shows the OP what I wrote in my answer "The ContentType you receive back depends on the web server implementation and is not guaranteed to be the same on each and every server" :)