# What is the relation between Mime Type and file extension

Tags: php, file, mime-types

my question is:
Is there some relation between a file extension and it's mime type? I mean, if i get a file, for instance, .php and change it's extension to .png will also change it's mime type?

Comment: Do not rely on the file extension the user gives you or the MIME type the browser tells you: both can be forged.  Use server side analysis (a la `file` or [`finfo_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php)) to identify the actual content.

Answer (score 6):

File extensions are hints as to the kind of data the file contains.  MIME types are labels for the kind of data in a file.  One file extension maps to at most one MIME type.  One MIME type maps to zero or more file extensions.  A good example is `image/jpeg`, which maps to both `.jpg` and `.jpeg`.

Theory aside, the MIME type a browser gives you is usually reliable, but if you *require certainty* you must then assume the browser has been compromised.

In such case, on the server using PHP, you can check that a given file matches a given MIME type with the FInfo extension:

```
$path = '/path/to/your/file.pdf';
$info = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
switch (finfo_file($info, $fpath)) {
case 'application/pdf':
    // hooray, this is what you want
    // do whatever
    break;

default:
    throw new RuntimeException('I said give me a PDF!');
}
```

Or if you want a simple function:

```
function is_mime_type($path, $mime) {
    return (finfo_file(finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE), $path) === $mime);
}

if (is_mime_type('/path/to/file.pdf', 'application/pdf')) {
    // hooray
}
```

Here is a [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23287341/how-to-get-mime-type-of-a-file-in-php-5-5) that documents other approaches to accomplish this goal.

And here's [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735659/list-of-all-mimetypes-on-the-planet-mapped-to-file-extensions) asking about the mapping between file extensions and MIME types.

Comment: Nice @bishop, that'' what i was looking for. I will check if it works.

Comment: Cool, let me know if not, I typed it up from memory without any syntax checking!

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: Yes.

Slightly longer answer: Mime types and file extensions provide hints to how to deal with a file. Whereas file extensions are commonly used for your OS to decide what program to open a file with, Mime types are used by your browser to decide how to present some data (or the server on how to interpret received data). Both are optional but it's a good practice to have an agreement. Changing the mime type a file is served as depends on your webserver. I believe Apache has settings somewhere to map from extensions to mime types. If you have your own back end serving content you can potentially serve content with any arbitrary mime type, for example, in PHP:

```
<?php
// We'll be outputting a PDF
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
...
```

or

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/javascript');
echo "//script code here"
```

Comment: Also for his other question, I don't think changing something's file extension would have any effect on its mime type.

Comment: Nice @Josep Valls thanks for your answer. I'm asking it because i need to have a strong verification in any file user upload in a system. Business require that application needs to check a file even if an user change it's extension knowingly, i thought that maybe if an user change it's extension i could even check the file by it's mime type, using php functions

Comment: @georaldc, if an user change a file extension, i still can guarantee it has a specific type by it's mime type?

Comment: Both are optional data that can be modified or faked so even mime type can't be a guarantee for you to know what file you are exactly dealing with. I believe a good way to approach this is to look at the contents of the file or use a whitelist of allowed file types and use specific php functions for checking if they are actually what they are (like using getimagesize() to detect valid images for example)