# nginx which content types to enable compression for

Tags: nginx, compression, gzip, mime-types, content-type

In several nginx tutorial sites explaining "how to set up gzip compression," I've seen this list of MIME types repeated:

`gzip_types text/plain text/html text/css application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;`

However, I immediately found that this list did not result in compression being enabled for JavaScript in Chromium. I had to add `application/javascript` to the list. Which leads me to believe this list is outdated.

Is there a definitive list of all the content types I would want to gzip?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no definitive list of the file types *you* would want to gzip. Any file type readable as plain text (i.e. non-binary files) are able to be gzipped, and so a "definitive" list would be massive. Therefore, it ultimately depends on which file types you are actually serving, which you can check for any given file via the HTTP `Content-Type` header.

If you want to be doubly sure you are covering all possible MIME types for a particular extension (which I think is reasonable), Looking at [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735659/list-of-all-mimetypes-on-the-planet-mapped-to-file-extensions), [this text file](https://s-randomfiles.s3.amazonaws.com/mime/allMimeTypes.txt) contains a pretty darn exhaustive list.

It's important to note that some binary file types like `.png` and `.pdf` (even `.woff`) incorporate compression into the format itself and as such should not be gzipped (because doing so could produce a compressed file larger than the original). My rule of thumb is: if my code editor can't read the file as UTF-8 text, gzipping the file would not be wise (or at least it wouldn't be very efficient).

FWIW, I typically gzip the following formats (in my Apache `.htaccess`) on my site:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/xml text/css text/javascript application/javascript application/x-javascript application/json application/xml image/svg+xml
</IfModule>
```